# How do I output only two numbers after a decimal place even for complex numbers?

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble outputting a number with only 2 decimal spaces after the decimal point.
For example, you divide 46/3 and get 15.3333. How would I change the output to 15.33 if I'm using the display (disp) function?

```
a = 46;
b = 3;
disp(a/b)  % 15.3333  <- this should be displayed as 15.33
```

Also this should work with complex numbers:

```
a = 46i;
b = 3;
disp(a/b)  % 0.0000 +15.3333i but I need 0.00 +15.33i
```

Comment: does disp(round(a/b, 2)) work?

Comment: You can set the global console output format with `format`. Use `format bank` to set the formatting of the output to two decimal places.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html

Comment: @kaladin_storm it still outputs four numbers after the decimal place

Comment: @naszy My output is a complex number so format bank technically works but it gets rid of the 'i' at the end of the number which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing complex numbers with two decimal places in both the real and imaginary part I suggest using the [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) with the Re and Im parts. For example, the following anonymous function implements this 2-decimal printing similar to the default Matlab format:

```matlab
disp2 = @(Z) fprintf('%.2f%+.2fi\n', real(Z), imag(Z));
```

Usage example:

```matlab
a = 10i;
b = 3;

disp2(a/b);     % 0.00+3.33i
disp2(-b-a);    % -3.00-10.00i
```

You can also replace the `fprintf` with `sprintf` and use the returned string inside a `disp()` function.

---

And this is a more complicated version of this function with nicer output:

```matlab
disp2 = @(z) fprintf('% 5.2f %c% 6.2fi\n', real(z), subsref(sprintf('%+d', imag(z)),struct('type','()','subs',{{1}})), abs(imag(z)));
```

E.g.

```matlab
disp2(a/b);     %  0.00 +  3.33i
disp2(-b-a);    % -3.00 - 10.00i
```